# Generating link Issue

Tags: php, getresponse

I want to generate link via on my user choice.

This is the dropbox code in the HTML

```
<select name="campaign_id">
    <?php foreach ( $campaigns as $campaignID => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $campaignID;?>"><?php echo $value->name;?></option>    
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

then i save the variable of choice.

```
$drop = $_POST['campaign_id'];
```

the token will be transferred to name in the dropdown . then i want the link to generate a link example. The value in $drop is a token value, is it possible to do something like the code below but instead

Comment: explain it more clearly? i didn't get it

Comment: Please, give an example of link

Comment: @user790454 , something like $link ="www.something.com"."The generated campaign ID convert to name as in the array for PHP"

Comment: @ЕгорГерасимчук , explained in the above.

Comment: still not clear for me ~ just show how the output want to be ?

Comment: @user790454, now when I echo $drop , it shows like a token 6F2Z . But during the dropbox value it shown in name such as campaign_id,testimonial,or maybe random words . So i want it to be like
www.something.com/campaign_id when the user pick the value of the dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
perhaps:

$drop = "www.something.com/" . "$_POST['campaign_id']";
```

Comment: but that would give a token value such as a7xgw instead of the campaign name.